# Getting MessageTypeNotSupportedException in Leanft

Tags: java, leanft

When I run simple test to open calc, I'm getting the following error:

```
com.hp.lft.sdk.MessageTypeNotSupportedException : Message type is not supported.
```

I'm using leanft in IntelliJ. Looks like a simple error but I'm unable to resolve it.

Comment: It would be most helpful to diagnose your code if you could share your code.

Comment: Interesting error. Not at all common for LeanFT. Can you provide more details on it? What code was used to trigger this error? And since you mention IntelliJ it means it didn't occur on eclipse? For the time being I will edit the post to remove the IntelliJ tag but please revert if I was mistaken